# Minitoc and import: how to specify location of mtc file?

Tags: table-of-contents, import, minitoc

In the project im working in, the structure is as follows

```
.
├── a
│   └── main.tex
├── b
│   └── main.tex
├── main.tex
```

The root main file is

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{minitoc}


\begin{document}
%
\dominitoc
\faketableofcontents

\import*{a/}{main}
\import*{b/}{main}
\end{document}
```

and the a/main.tex and b/main.tex files would ideally be

```
\chapter{Chapter}
\minitoc
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
```

Unfortunately, the minitoc doesn't appear. After compiling, I have in the root directory various mtc files (for readability, most files are hidden out)

```
.
├── [4.0K]  a
│   └── [  69]  main.tex
├── [4.0K]  b
│   └── [  69]  main.tex
├── [   0]  main.mtc
├── [   0]  main.mtc0
├── [ 266]  main.mtc1
├── [ 266]  main.mtc2
├── [ 19K]  main.pdf
├── [ 284]  main.tex
└── [ 192]  main.toc
```

But main.log complains

```
(./a/main.tex¶                                                                                             | 
    Chapter 1.¶                                                                                                | 
    Package minitoc Info: I0006¶                                                                               | 
    (minitoc)             main.mtc1 is empty on input line 3.¶
```

The way I found to get the minitoc is to copy/paste main.mtc1 in a/. and main.mtc2 in b/. So, obviously, because of the command import{a/}{main}, minitoc looks for the mtc files in the a/ and b/ directories (which is obviously the role of import...).

Another solution I found is to add a minitoc.tex file in the root directory

```
.
├── a
│   └── main.tex
├── b
│   └── main.tex
├── main.tex
├── minitoc.tex
```

Which contains just

```
\minitoc
```

and to change a/main.tex and b/main.tex as follows

```
\chapter{Chapter}
\setcounter{mtc}{1}%Or 2, according to the chapter number
\import{../}{minitoc}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
```

The trouble of this solution is that I have to set the counter manually. It's not that bad, but is there any better automatic solution ?

Comment: I suggest to use `\input{a/main}` instead, and write `\faketableofcontents` to `main.tex`.

Comment: Hi Christian. Thanks for the answer. The problem is that I'd like to use import and note input/include since my real folder setup has more steps down (I mean, 3 or 4 nested folders and inputs). Using import helps me to move folders across the hierarchy without changing the paths in the various inputs.

Comment: And btw, what's the point of moving the faketableofcontents ?